# Postgresql nested function and transaction

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about the postgresql nested function and transaction. As you know, each function in postgresql is in a transaction. I am curious about if the inner function failed, will all the changes made in the outer function rolled back?

here is the one example

```
function 1(){

   insert some data into table 1;
   call function2
   insert some data into table 2;


}
```

Will the "insertions in table 1 " rollback if there is some error in function2?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unless you set a savepoint to which you can rollback.

In PL/pgSQL, this is implicitly done with a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END;` block, so the following won't rollback the first `INSERT`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function 1() RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   insert some data into table 1;
   BEGIN
      function2();
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN others THEN  /* catch any exception */
         NULL;  / ignore error */
   END;
   insert some data into table 2;
END;$$;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) for details.

In other languages there are different ways to do it.